# alterar diretório root nginx

Tags: nginx

---

## objetivo: alterar o diretório root padrão.

abaixo demonstrarei as configurações atuais configuradas com o intuito de alguém possivelmente entender e me dizer o que está equivocadamente errado, faltando...

---

observação que demonstrarei aqui apenas a primeiro linha do arquivo **nginx.conf** pois ele é grande e seria desnecessário o código todo, segue a primeira linha do arquivo **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
```

---

arquivo **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/website;
    index index.htm index.html;
    server_name website;
    location / {
    autoindex on;
 }
}
```

---

permissão e detalhes da pasta **/var/www/website**

*-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Nov 13 04:57 index.html*

---

no caso efetuei esse comando:

### sudo chown -R root:root /var/www/website

também testei assim:

### sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/website

independente dos dois ñ obtive sucesso, peço p/ que antes de negativar seja solidário pois estou qse passando fome.

espero que minha questão e demonstração de minha configuração fracassada seja de fácil entendimento, em outras palavras espero ter sido claro em minha dúvida, qualquer atenção mediante resposta será de grande avalia. thanks

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta configuração só vai funcionar para o nome de domínio **website**, ou seja, quando alguém tentar acessar `http://website`

Se o Nginx está configurado para rodar com o usuário www-data, então as configurações de usuário e grupo corretas são estas:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/website
```

Está fora do escopo da tua pergunta, mas pra garantir que as permissões de arquivos e diretórios estejam corretas **CONTANTO** que tu não tenha scripts cgi que devem ser executáveis (se tu não sabe, provavelmente não tem):

```
sudo find /var/www/website -type d -exec chmod 0755 '{}' \;
sudo find /var/www/website -type f -exec chmod 0644 '{}' \;
```

O teu arquivo **index.html** está com as permissões **incorretas** (*rwxrwxrwx* que é equivalente a 0777). As permissões corretas para arquivos são *rw-r--r--* equivalente a 0644, e para diretórios *rwxr-xr-x* equivalente a 0755.

Se tu quiser alterar somente o diretório e o arquivo que tu tem:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /var/www/website
sudo chmod 0644 /var/www/website/index.html
```

Ou então com estes comandos equivalentes:

```
sudo chmod 'u=rwx,go=rx' /var/www/website
sudo chmod 'u=rw,go=r' /var/www/website/index.html
```

---

Para definir um diretório root padrão para todo e qualquer site que não esteja configurado (por exemplo se alguém tentar acessar o servidor web usando o endereço ipv4), tu precisa criar um bloco de servidor padrão. Eu particularmente na minha instalação crio o seguinte arquivo:

Conteúdo de **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default-server.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/default;
}
```

Esta configuração vai "capturar" todo e qualquer site que não estiver configurado (os que estão em **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled**). Se tu souber ler em inglês, na documentação oficial tem a explicação de como são processadas as requisições: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Os sites que tu configurar em **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled** vão usar outro diretório root conforme a configuração de cada um. Mas quando o Nginx não conseguir achar o diretório root de algum site, ele vai usar este padrão definido nesta configuração.

---

Sempre lembrando que pra testar a configuração antes de reiniciar ou recarregar o serviço:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Comment: tks luri, segui oq tu disse e tbm visualizei uns tutoriais asiáticos/ingleses p/ melhor entendimento deu certo, em relação ao comando chown www-data parece obvio + 100 entendimento visualizei root na pasta padrão nginx arrisquei atoa o outro comando, enfim resolvido forte abraço (y)